# Database structure for a classifieds website

Tags: mysql, database-design, solr, faceted-search

I am developing a classifieds website similar to Quickr.com.

The main problem is that each category requires a different set of properties. For example, for a mobile phone the attributes might be Manufacturer, Operating System, Is Touch Screen, Is 3G enabled etc... Whereas for an apartment the attributes are Number of bedrooms, Is furnished, Which floor, total area etc. Since the attributes and the number of attributes varies for each category, I am keeping the attributes and their values in separate tables.

My current database structure is

### Table classifieds_ads

This table stores all the ads. One record per ad.

**ad_id**
ad_title
ad_desc
ad_created_on
cat_id

**Sample data**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|ad_id | ad_title    | ad_desc                                       | ad_created_on | cat_id |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1     | Nokia Phone | Nokia n97 phone for sale. Excellent condition | <timestamp>   | 2      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Table classifieds_cat

This table stores all the available category. cat_id in classifieds_ads table relates to cat_id in this table.

**cat_id**
category
parent_cid

**Sample data**

```
-------------------------------------------
|cat_id| category            | parent_cid |
-------------------------------------------
|1     | Electronics         | NULL       |
|2     | Mobile Phone        | 1          |
|3     | Apartments          | NULL       |
|4     | Apartments - Sale   | 3          |
-------------------------------------------
```

### Table classifieds_attribute

This table contains all the available attributes for a particular category. Relates to classifieds_cat table.

**attr_id**
cat_id
input_type
attr_label
attr_name

**Sample data**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|attr_id | cat_id | attr_label       | attr_name          |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|1       | 2      | Operating System | Operating_System   |
|2       | 2      | Is Touch Screen  | Touch_Screen       |
|3       | 2      | Manufacturer     | Manufacturer       |
|4       | 3      | Bedrooms         | Bedrooms           |
|5       | 3      | Total Area       | Area               |
|6       | 3      | Posted By        | Posted_By          |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

### Table classifieds_attr_value

This table stores the attribute value for each ad in classifieds_ads table.

**attr_val_id**
attr_id
ad_id
attr_val

**Sample data**

```
---------------------------------------------
|attr_val_id | attr_id | ad_id | attr_val   |
---------------------------------------------
|1           | 1       | 1     | Symbian OS |
|2           | 2       | 1     | 1          |
|3           | 3       | 1     | Nokia      |
---------------------------------------------
```

========

- Is this design okay?
- Is it possible to index this data with solr?
- How can I perform a faceted search on this data?
- Does MySQL support field collapsing like solr?

Comment: The structure seems OK but searching will be a bit complex. Do you need help with the search query?

Comment: Thanks. I am able to get the data as required via SQL. It is faceted search that I am mainly interested in. But from what I understand, faceted search requires fixed fields.

Comment: It's not a good idea to ask 4 questions in one post. You get more reactions if you split these up into 4 (much less verbose) questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is fine, although I question why you are using hierarchical categories.  I understand that you want to organize categories from an end-user standpoint.  The hierarchy helps them drill down to the category that they are looking for.  However, your schema allows for attribute values at every level.  I would suggest that you only need (or possibly want) attributes at the leaf level.

It is certainly possible that you could come up with attributes that would be applicable at higher levels, but this would drastically complicate your management of the data since you'd have to spend a lot of time thinking about exactly how high up the chain a certain attribute belongs and whether or not there is some reason why a lower level might be an exception to the parent rule and so forth.

It also certainly over complicates your retrieveal as well - which is part of the reason for your question, I think.

I would suggest creating an additional table that will be used to manage the hierarchy of categories above the leaf level.  It would look exactly like your `classifieds_cat` table except the involuted relationship will obviously be to the new table.  Then `classifieds_cat.parent_cid` becomes an FK to the new table rather than an involuted FK to `classifieds_cat`.

I think this schema change will reduce your application and data management complexity.

Comment: Thanks Joel. Entries are possible at higher levels too. There might be a case where a particular entry might not fit in any of the sub categories. Under such circumstance, the entry can be posted in the parent category. Actually, there is another field `allow_listing` under `classifieds_cat`, which I omitted in the above design to simplify the structure, which decides whether a particular category can have ad listing or not.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to remove `cat_id` from the `classifieds_attribute` table, then create a new table.

The new table would look like:

```
cat_attr | id | cat_id | attr_id
```

This should help you decrease redundancy.